# Firebase - In security rules how do I restrict a user to only update an object that they originally created?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

**Firebase** - In security rules how do I restrict a user to only update an object that they originally created.

So they cannot update another persons object?

**Current security rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {

    "organisations": {
        "$uid": {
           ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
           ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"        
        }
    }

  }
}
```

This prevents the user doing anything.

**This is the firebase organisations table:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can check on the `auth.uid` variable and the `newData` variable.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "organisations": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['uid'])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means that your data must have a `uid` property.

[Check out the Firebase Security Guide for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html)

[Also, you may want to check out the Bolt compiler.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/bolt/quickstart.html)

Comment: Hi David, I've added my current security rules above.
I'm trying to get the logged in user to read and write if thats there object

Comment: Can you show what the organization data looks like? And is the organization location keyed off of the user's `uid`?

Comment: I've added the table above

Comment: Are you storing this data by `organization/$uid` or is it `organization/$organization_id`?

Comment: An organisation key is the uid and I've also put an organisations uid as a child field

Comment: If the `$uid` key is the the authenticated user's `uid`, then the rules above should work. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: il try it again. When I did this last time the data wouldnt read or write